# Storing and loading functions

Tags: c++, c++11, template, boost

The class `Functions` can store/load any functions. It does this by assigning a unique name to every function that gets added. You can then call the function by specifying its name and return type.

Here is a sample usage

```
//Create class
Functions funcs;

//Add 2 functions (foo -> void(int, int) | add -> int(int, int))
funcs.add("foo", foo);
funcs.add("add", add);

//Call them
int r = funcs.call<int>("add", 3, 2);
funcs.call<void>("foo", r, 2);
```

Here is the actual class

```
class Functions
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void add(std::string name, T(*func)(Ts...))
    {
        mFunctions.insert(std::make_pair(name, func));
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    T call(std::string name, Ts... args)
    {
        try
        {
            return boost::any_cast<T(*)(Ts...)>(mFunctions.at(name))(args...);
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range&)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Function doesn't exist!");
        }
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> mFunctions;
};
```

Is there anything to be improved, like maybe naming, programming techniques, ...? Some general feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [*perfect forwarding*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) in the call method to preserve the type qualifiers. Right now the arguments are always copied, which might be inefficient for more complex user defined types.

```
template<typename RetType, typename... Args>
RetType call(const std::string& name, Args&&... args) const
{
    // ... lookup ...
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Also note that the function name can be taken by `const ref`, since you just need to look it up. No additional copies are required.

It also seems adequate to `const` qualify the method, since it will not alter the underlaying map container.

Speaking of `std::map`, I would avoid it in favor of the newer [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). `std::map` is a BTree, so it is guaranteed to allocate memory at each insertion for its internal tree nodes, making it memory and cache inefficient. `unordered_map` is a hash table, so it should have better average lookup time and allocate memory less often. I suggest using it as the new default for key+value store unless you are certain `map` is more efficient in your usage case.

> ```
>    try
>    {
>        return boost::any_cast<T(*)(Ts...)>(mFunctions.at(name))(args...);
>    }
>    catch (const std::out_of_range&)
>    {
>        throw std::invalid_argument("Function doesn't exist!");
>    }
> ```

This is not incorrect or bad code, but map and unordered_map also have lookup methods that don't throw. Code that doesn't generate exceptions tend to be more efficient and might even convey intent more clearly. Alternatively, using the `find` method:

```
const auto iter = mFunctions.find(name);
if (iter == std::end(mFunctions))
{
    // throw
}

const auto func = boost::any_cast<T(*)(Args&&...)>(iter.second);
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a good start.
But function pointers are not the only type callable objects. Functors were a big part of C++03 and with C++11 lambdas are even more important.

Rather than using:

```
T(*func)(Ts...)
```

Which handles function pointers. You can generalize this with `std::function<>`.

```
std::function<T(Ts...)>
```

Which generalizes the callable construct.